# How can I add items to a numpy hstack in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

This code..

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
for k in range(0, len(array)):
    final_array = np.hstack(array[k, :])
print(final_array)
```

Will only print the last [3,4,5] not the entire array in an hstack.

I tried doing **final_array += np.hstack(array[k, :])**, but Python gives me an error. Also tried to reshape the array before concatenation.

**My goal is to add the array items to the hstack in reverse order so I think I need to use a loop -- and not just insert the entire array into an hstack call.**

All the examples I've found online are simple where you have two arrays and you call hstack. But, I haven't found any that combine successive arrays in a loop.

I'm assuming this is simple, but the solution escapes me.

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop keeps overwriting `final_array` with a new value, so at the end you're left with just that from the last loop iteration.

Building arrays using loops like this is losing game, it is very slow.  Instead, just say `np.hstack(array)` and get it all done in one go.  This will be 10-100x faster.

Comment: Brilliant. I missed that simple solution! Thank you. It works great.

Comment: One question though ... what if I need to reverse the order of the array items in the final hstack? That's why I was using a loop. Can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Morkus: You mean you want `[3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]` ?  Then just do `np.hstack(array[::-1])` to reverse the input before stacking.